# FilterInputStream that supports readLine

Tags: java, antlr, readline, bufferedinputstream

I would like to implement a `FilterInputStream` that supports `BufferedInputStream` interface and in particular the `readLine()` method.

The current code looks like this (standard antlr):

```
theInput = new BufferedInputStream( Files.newInputStream(inputPath) );
theOutput = new PrintStream(Files.newOutputStream(outputPath));

grammar.execute(theInput, theOutput);
```

The proposed code would look something like this:

```
theInput = new RemoveCommentsInputStream( Files.newInputStream(inputPath) );
theOutput = new PrintStream(Files.newOutputStream(outputPath));

grammar.execute(theInput, theOutput);
```

Where `RemoveCommentsInputStream` would work something like `java.io.FilterInputStream`.

The problem is that `FilterInputStream` extends `InputStream`, but `execute()` takes a `BufferedInputStream`.

The use case for this is I want to write a filter that will remove the comments and other cruft for the code before I pass it to antlr.  Implementing rules to handle the cruft in antlr would difficult because the rules are based on the column position of certain characters in the input.  But it would be easy to get rid of in plain old java.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not understand. `BufferedInputStream` doesn't have a `readLine()` method; you don't need a `readLine()` method to remove comments; and there is nothing stopping you from wrapping your filter in a `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: There's also nothing stopping you from extending `BufferedInputStream` instead of `FilterInputStream`, but wrapping is better.

Comment: Think you would like to deal with BufferedReader instead. Process texts directly with InputStream isn't a good practice.